# Clutch Pedal Feels A Bit Grindy

Tags: clutch, mazda, gears, mazda-3

Mazda 3 Sport 2017 with 22,000 Miles on the clock ( car had 20,000 miles when I purchased it )

Recently sometimes the pedal feels a bit grindy when bringing the pedal back upwards. The higher the revs the more I feel it.

For example, sat in neutral 1,000 revs it is fine. But if the revs are 3,500 and upwards it feels a bit grindy ( in any gear, even neutral )
Low revs, it isn't an issue. But high revs I feel it.

No odd noises, gear shifts are fine.

Any ideas, is anybody elses like this ?
When I first got the car I would rest my foot on the clutch sometimes but weeks ago have tried to stop doing that.

Comment: If there are no odd noises and it shifts fine, could you better explain what you mean by "grindy"? What exactly do you feel? And yes, do not rest your foot on the clutch pedal. This is what is called "riding the clutch" and will absolutely lead to excessive clutch wear and early replacement.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I mean, it feels a bit rough at high revs, mainly when bring the pedal back upwards rather than nice and smooth. It moves up and down fine. And at low revs it's smooth with no issues.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to check out:

1. The clutch pedal mechanism itself. Today, most clutches are hydraulic and therefore have a master and slave cylinder.  The pivot on your brake pedal, the master cylinder itself, the slave cylinder, or the pivot on the slave mechanism may be worn or in need of lube and are causing the "grinding" sensation.
2. A more expensive problem is that the throw-out bearing is worn or damaged and it is no longer sliding smoothly on the transmission shaft.  This likely means you have to remove the transmission and fix it and in most cases you'll want to go ahead and replace the clutch too since you're 90% of the way there at this point.

Comment: Even if It shifts gears fine with no odd noises ? The car has only done 22,000 miles. Any real problems or if it gets worse then I'll have to speak to Mazda

Comment: You would hear a bad throwout bearing, at least when it's due to be replaced. You'll hear it whine in a descending tone as it drops from engine revs to zero (or to the next gear). Somewhat like a turbo spooling down, but rapidly

Comment: Not a huge chance of the actual pedal-related mechanisms to be worn out at 22K miles. The throwout bearing may be fine, but the shaft may be damaged, its surface may be corroded, or otherwise not smooth. This may cause rough feeling on the pedal.

Comment: I agree it should not have these problems at 22K miles but...  You would not be the first person to get a car with a defective part from the factory.

Comment: The time I feel it most is when the blue cold engine light is on when in neutral. When the revs start to drop and the light goes off it pretty much disappears and feels fine.